# Odd bounded function limit at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

> $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  is a bounded odd function. What can be said about $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$?
>
> 1. Must be $0$
> 2. If exists then $0$
> 3. Must exist but may not be $0$

I am stuck at this question. I know, for *continuous* odd function we must have value $0$ at $x=0$. But we don't know if this function is continuous or not. How to proceed?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By odd parity,

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x).$$

If those limits exist, they must be equal for the ordinary limit to exist, hence 2.

Comment: Why are you saying that the limit may not exist? I cannot think of any counterexample here

Comment: @user587126 Take the function which is $0$ at $x = 0$, $1$ on $\mathbb R^+$, and $-1$ on $\mathbb R^-$.

Comment: @AlexProvost  Now i get it. Thanks man!

Comment: @user587126: because limits are not "obliged" to exist !

Comment: @AlexProvost: this example does not answer the OP's remark, both left and right limits exist !

Comment: @YvesDaoust  i don't see why. The limit at $0$ does not exist let alone be equal to zero.

Comment: @user587126 Consider 

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, &\text{ if $x\notin \mathbb{Q}, x > 0$}\\
-1, &\text{ if $x\notin \mathbb{Q}, x < 0$}\\
0, &\text{ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$}\\
\end{cases}$$
Then $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)$ both don't exist.

Comment: @user587126: both the left and right limits exist ($-1$ and $1$) but the limit does not. So this does not address your objection. I think you are confusing the three limits.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't understand your remark. I was simply giving an example of the ordinary limit not existing for an odd bounded function.

Comment: @AlexProvost: there is a misunderstanding. The OP commented about "the limit may not exist", when I was saying "the limitS may not exist". The limitS may fail to exist like any limit, and the limit mail fail for two different reasons.